# disable anchor tag first click on devices and need to work second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DOM like this. when i click the anchor tag first time on devices i want to disable the anchor tag. and second click it will go to the url, good answers must be appreciated.

```js
$(function(){

var oreintedWidth = $(window).width();
if (oreintedWidth < 1200) {
var $clickLinks = $('.social').find('ul').children('li');
   $($clickLinks).on('click', 'a', function(events){

      $($clickLinks).each(function(index, element) {
         $(this).closest('li').removeClass('selected');
      });
  
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
      if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('selected')){
         events.preventDefault();
      }else {}     
   });
}

});
```

```html
<div class="social">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">three</a></li>
    </ul><!-- /.ul -->
</div>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334673/edit-clearly-violating-my-answer-voted-approve-by-reviewer and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334675/code-snippets-are-a-pest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i got it. this is what i am looking for , thanks for the support

```js
$(function(){

    var oreintedWidth = $(window).width();
    if (oreintedWidth < 1200) {
    var $clickLinks = $('.social').find('ul').children('li');
     $($clickLinks).find('a').attr('onClick','return false');
     $($clickLinks).on('click', 'a', function(events){
      var nearBy = $(this).closest('li');
      
      $($clickLinks).each(function(index, element) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
             $(this).find('a').attr('onClick','return false');
            });
      
      nearBy.addClass('selected');
      if(nearBy.hasClass('selected'))
      {
       $(this).attr('onClick',"return true");
       
      }
      else {
       $(this).attr('onClick','return false');
       
      }
      
      
     });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, is this what you want.I just added an alert, add your code instead of that. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<body>
 

<a href="" class="mylink">MY LINK, I WILL NOT WORK IN THE FIRST CLICK</a>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var theclick = 0;
  $(".mylink").click(function(event){
   if(theclick == 0)
   {
    theclick = theclick + 1;
    event.preventDefault();
   }
   else
   {
          //do your code here
    alert("Yeh, this is the second time, now I'm working");
   }
  });
 });


</script>
</html>
```

copy paste and try it in  your browser.

or else, you want to show the disable with css when first click do like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">
a.mylink{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.adisable{
 color:gray;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

</style>

<body>
 

<a href="" target="_blank" class="mylink">MY LINK, I WILL NOT WORK IN THE FIRST CLICK</a>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var theclick = 0;
  $(".mylink").click(function(event){
   if(theclick == 0)
   {
    theclick = theclick +1;
    $(this).addClass("adisable");
    event.preventDefault();
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Yeh, this is the second time, no I wil work");
   }
  });
 });


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. but this is not what i wanted

Comment: then what you want

Comment: check with my DOM , i have 3 li , when i click the a tag add a class to the closest li.. and the only anchors to ready for go to url

Comment: and the 3 li got multiple anchors all are ready when the li got selected class. its a simple logic i think. i am keep working on it

Answer (score 1):

You can use one() method to track first click and then you can change attribute or class. on other click event you can check attribute or class is set or not? and propogate event based on class or attribute set

```js
$(function(){

var oreintedWidth = $(window).width();
if (oreintedWidth < 1200) {
var $clickLinks = $('.social > ul> li > a ');
 $($clickLinks).one('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).attr('first-clicked','1');
      return false;
 });
  
    $($clickLinks).on('click', function(e){
     
     return $(this).attr('first-clicked')=='1';
 });
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank" first-clicked='0'>one</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank" first-clicked='0'>two</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank" first-clicked='0'>three</a></li>
    </ul><!-- /.ul -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is good. but when i click one add attribute `first-clicked` next i click two that also got first-clicked and agian i reach to one thats go to link. thats not i wanted. i got the answer and i posted on top